# Newest version of orocos kdl

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, orocos, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone
I tried to use the inverse dynamics solver for trees ([documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/orocos_kdl/html/classKDL_1_1TreeIdSolver__RNE.html)) from the kinematis and dynamics library (kdl). I have installed the newest version of kdl with :

sudo apt install ros-melodic-orocos-kdl

So it should be the newest version (1.4.0-0bionic.20200303.062327).

But when i looked at the folder in /opt/ros/melodic/include/kdl there was no treeidsolver_recursive_newton_euler.hpp file, although according to the above mentioned documentation and this [github repository](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/tree/master/orocos_kdl/src) it should be there.
I managed to do a workaround by simply copying the necessary files into the folder manually and adapting some others so they are compatible and it somehow works. But i guess this is a horrible way to do it and i am not sure if it is not going to break down when i try different stuff.

Can anyone tell me how i would do this the "right" way?

I also tried to create an account on the orocos webpage but when i responded to the invitation email like required i got an "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender". Is this website and the orocos project even running anymore?

(i am using ubuntu 18.04 and ros melodic)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354654/newest-version-of-orocos-kdl/) by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this github issue](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/issues/263) for the answer.

---

Originally posted by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) with karma: 54 on 2020-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0